# Flex 3: How do I reference the Modal Button in a Custom Component?

Tags: apache-flex, popup, modal-dialog

I've got a custom component based on a TitleWindow. I want to put an event listener in my main app that listens for the Titlewindow's modal button's click

Custom Component:

```
<mx:TitleWindow 
  showCloseButton="true" 
  close="closeHandler(event)">
```

blah blah...

```
<mx:TitleWindow>
```

In the main app:

I've got a variable called popWindow, which is the above component. How do I reference the TitleWindow's modal button?

I want to do something like this:

(Pseudo-code)
popWindow.[modal button reference].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction);

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the event listener to popWindow directly? That MouseEvent should bubble; you will have to check the target on it though to make sure it is the click you are looking for.

Edit: you could also dispatch out a new event in your close handler and listen for that event on this outside, by just adding an event dispatcher on your popWindow as well.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the help. As you suggested, I put a listener on popWindow directly. I found the closeEvent. popWindow.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, turnOffButton2);